# selectContextMenuItem method returning "The method got an invalid argument"

Tags: blueprism, sap-gui

I'm trying to sort a table in SAP in Blue Prism. The code previously worked fine but now I'm getting the following error message when I try to sort the table by context menu item.

> The method got an invalid argument

I've tried passing a variety of values to the selectContextMenuItem method: "&SORT_DSC", "&SORT_ASC", "&COL_INV"...all yield the same error.

```
Dim SAPGuiAuto as Object
Dim SAPApp as Object
Dim SAPCon as Object
Dim session as Object
Dim Table as Object

SAPGuiAuto = Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction.GetObject("SAPGUI")
SAPApp = SAPGuiAuto.GetScriptingEngine
SAPCon = SAPApp.Children(0)
session = SAPCon.Children(0)

Table = session.findById("/app/con[0]/ses[0]/wnd[0]/usr/cntlGRID1/shellcont/shell")
Table.setCurrentCell("-1", "LMENGEIST")
Table.selectColumn("LMENGEIST")
Table.contextMenu
Table.selectContextMenuItem("&SORT_DSC")
```

I expect the column I've selected to be sorted in descending order.

Thanks in advance for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old question but I just started receiving this same error in my C# Console Application (.NET Framework v4.6) after months of the program running autonomously. The only difference is that I was attempting to select a Layout Variant using the filter. Additionally, the application only failed when I ran it as a scheduled task.

First, I did as Sandra suggested and executed the action manually. Whilst doing so, I used SAP's script recording feature to find out if the script used a different argument. I found that the script still used the same argument ("&FILTER"); but I also noticed that the table took a half second to initialize. So I added a few `Thread.Sleep()` - one after the button click (to give the Variant Select window time to initialize) and one after clicking the context menu (to give the menu time to initialize) - and now, my program now runs as smoothly as it did previously.

```
                //Execute Report
            ((GuiMainWindow)SAPActive.SAPsession.FindById("wnd[0]")).SendVKey(8);

            //Change Layout
            ((GuiButton)SAPActive.SAPsession.FindById("wnd[0]/tbar[1]/btn[33]")).Press();
            Thread.Sleep(2000);
            ((GuiGridView)SAPActive.SAPsession.FindById("wnd[1]/usr/ssubD0500_SUBSCREEN:SAPLSLVC_DIALOG:0501/cntlG51_CONTAINER/shellcont/shell")).CurrentCellRow = -1;
            ((GuiGridView)SAPActive.SAPsession.FindById("wnd[1]/usr/ssubD0500_SUBSCREEN:SAPLSLVC_DIALOG:0501/cntlG51_CONTAINER/shellcont/shell")).SelectColumn("VARIANT");
            ((GuiGridView)SAPActive.SAPsession.FindById("wnd[1]/usr/ssubD0500_SUBSCREEN:SAPLSLVC_DIALOG:0501/cntlG51_CONTAINER/shellcont/shell")).ContextMenu();
            Thread.Sleep(2000);
            ((GuiGridView)SAPActive.SAPsession.FindById("wnd[1]/usr/ssubD0500_SUBSCREEN:SAPLSLVC_DIALOG:0501/cntlG51_CONTAINER/shellcont/shell")).SelectContextMenuItem("&FILTER");
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message `The method got an invalid argument` is very specific to SAP GUI Scripting methods, and can be recognized by the missing word `has` (before `got`).

It's a general purpose message which is sent when a method of SAP GUI Scripting has an argument which doesn't correspond to an expected value.

In your case, it would probably mean that the item `&SORT_DSC` does not exist in the context menu. Make sure that if you execute the action manually in the SAP GUI, you see this context menu and the option to sort in descending order.

NB: for information, this message may occur in a variety of other SAP GUI functions, for instance with `fileID = application.utils.openfile("file-name.log")`, just because the character "`-`" is not allowed in the file name.